# What is the practical application of the setChunked method of Vert.x-Web?

Tags: vert.x

I'm starting my study on Vert.x and in its documentation I came across a feature that divides the routing of a request into parts. This functionality is activity through the response.setChunked (true) methods. I understood its fution and I have already done some examples. However, I can not think of a practical application of this functionality. I ask: what would be its practical application, in a real scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the HTTP Chunked Transfer Encoding, you keep open the HTTP connection and keep sending data to the client. Also, in this case you omit the Content-Length header. This is ideal for any kind of streaming service. For further info check out this: https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/chunked/